# NSURLRequest on iOS vs OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Is there any difference between NSURLRequest class on Mac OS and iOS?

Apparently there is one.

Here how the class description looks on Mac OS:

```
<NSURLRequest: 0x60000000f290> { URL: http://www.google.com/ }
```

And here how it looks on iOS:

```
<NSURLRequest http://www.google.com/>
```

As it appears there is a big difference for my project as it work perfectly on iOS and connection fails for Mac OS version.

Does anyone know how to make Mac OS app init the NSURLRequest class object exactly the way it does for iOS?

**UPD 1**
Same code for initialisation of the object for both platforms

```
NSURLRequest* aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];
```

I tried same to use NSURLRequest in both AFNetworking and NSURLConnection getting same result - successful connection on iOS and 403 error for Mac OS

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your source for initializing your `NSURLRequest` on both platforms?

Comment: Give your codes in Mac OS.

Comment: @IanMacDonald code is the same for both platforms NSURLRequest* aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

Comment: There's no substantial difference, other than possibly in areas that the interface makes no promises about like `description`, but obviously default things like the user agent will vary. Show us your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> successful connection on iOS and 403 error for Mac OS

403 is HTTP's `Forbidden` response. The fact that you're getting a 403 means that a) your request is making a proper HTTP connection, but b) the server doesn't want to talk to you for some reason. A good strategy for diagnosing the issue is to use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to look at the successful and unsuccessful requests and note the differences. The user agent parameter is one thing that's likely to differ between the two platforms, but you'll probably find other differences as well. Once you know what's different between the two requests, you'll have a better idea of what you need to change to make the failing requests work.

Comment: Thanks, I had find out that the problem is not in the request but somewhere in other data I use. It is just that difference in description of the class mislead me.